# How to set a device admin app to default launcher without prompt in a rooted device?

Tags: android

I have a rooted device where I have successfully made my app a device admin app and a home application launcher too but the user is given the choice to start my app or the default Google launcher. I'd like to always have my app be the default launcher. Is there a way to do this without the user interaction ?